# How do I access a Map that's imported from a text file in another class?

Tags: java, class, treemap

I have three classes (Main, Product and Counter). Product creates a new TreeMap named mProductMap. Product also has an export method to write the TreeMap to a text file. With the import method it reads from it. The text file is already created when I run Main. The Counter class uses the TreeMap to do calculations with the values of the keys.

All methods in Product and Counter used to be in the same class, until I decided it would be better practice to separate certain methods in their own class. I'm trying to access the TreeMap in the Counter class with the getter method from Product and then use the methods from Counter on it.

**The problem:** When everything was in the same class, everything worked. Now that I put methods in separate Classes, the Counter methods can't read what's in the TreeMap. It returns the else statement: "Key1 does not exist. Please try again."

Can anyone please explain to me what's going on and how to fix this?
I don't know if it's important info but: classes Product and Counter are in the same package. Main imports that package.

Main class:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Product product = new Product();
        Counter counter = new Counter();
        product.importFrom("prices.txt");
        counter.add("Key1");
        counter.add("Key2");
        counter.add("Key3");
        product.exportTo("prices.txt");
    }
}
```

Product class:

```
public class Product {
    private TreeMap<String, BigDecimal> mProductMap = new TreeMap<>();

    public TreeMap<String, BigDecimal> getProductMap() {
        return mProductMap;
    }

    public void setProductMap(TreeMap<String, BigDecimal> productMap) {
        mProductMap = productMap;
    }

    public void addProduct(String product, BigDecimal price) {
        mProductMap.put(product, price);
    }

    public void exportTo(String fileName) {
        try (
                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(fileName);
                PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(fos);
        ) {
            for(Map.Entry<String, BigDecimal> entry : mProductMap.entrySet()) {
                writer.printf("%s|%s%n",
                        entry.getKey(),
                        entry.getValue());
            }
        } catch(IOException ioe) {
            System.out.printf("Problem saving %s %n", fileName);
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void importFrom(String fileName) {
        try (
                FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(fileName);
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fis));
        ) {
            String line;
            while((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                String[] args = line.split("\\|");
                addProduct(args[0], new BigDecimal(args[1]));
            }
        } catch(IOException ioe) {
            System.out.printf("Problems loading %s %n", fileName);
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Counter class:

```
public class Counter {
    private BigDecimal total = new BigDecimal("0.00");
    Product p = new Product();

    private TreeMap<String, BigDecimal> newMap = p.getProductMap();

    public void add(String product) {
        if (newMap.containsKey(product)) {
            BigDecimal price = newMap.get(product);
            total = total.add(price);
        } else {
            System.out.printf("%s does not exist. Please try again.%n", product);
        }
        System.out.printf("Adding %s. Total is %s%n", product, total);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is here (inside `Counter`):

```
Product p = new Product();

private TreeMap<String, BigDecimal> newMap = p.getProductMap();
```

The instance of `Product` (variable `p`) is not the same instance that loaded the text file in your `main` method.  Each instance of `Product` will have its own `mProductMap` collection.

#### Suggestion for Fixing

Instead of having `Counter` create a private copy of `Product`, you could pass an instance of `Product` to the constructor of `Counter`...

```
public class Counter {
    private BigDecimal total = new BigDecimal("0.00");
    private final Product p;

    public Counter(Product p) {
        this.p = p;
    }

    public void add(String product) {
        TreeMap<String, BigDecimal> pMap = p.getProductMap();
        if (pMap.containsKey(product)) {
            BigDecimal price = pMap.get(product);
            total = total.add(price);
        } else {
            System.out.printf("%s does not exist. Please try again.%n", product);
        }
        System.out.printf("Adding %s. Total is %s%n", product, total);
    }
}
```

And then in your `main` method, create your `Counter` like this...

```
Counter counter = new Counter(product);
```